Shader settings will not affect my rig, but affects other objects
So I've been creating some artwork for a while now and I wanted to try cell shading my rig as I'm always wanting to try different lighting styles. A problem I realized though is I believe Blender doesn't recognize this rig as an object. If I make a simple cell shader in Eevee and turn on rendering, it affects anything else (cube, UV sphere) but my rig remains unphased. Moreover I can't use nodes on it; Blender won't let me. Maybe it's because this is a pre made rig I got from someone else but this is really grinding my gears. Is there anyway I can resolve this?
Here's the link to the rig(s) by the way, it's an add-on. Maybe someone can play around with this and help me out: https://softgb.gumroad.com/l/robloxstarterrigs

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Materials/shaders can only be assigned to mesh faces, either real mesh objects or procedural meshes created by modifiers like the Skin or Geometry Nodes modifiers etc., or for example curves which get "meshed" by giving them extrusion, bevel or profile and likewise. An exception are also lights, which can have shader nodes for emission. Objects like empties, cameras and armatures cannot have shaders. Anything which disappears when you turn off the Viewport Overlays basically.
